# Having trouble printing objects with __str__ in Python

Tags: python, sql, oop

I am having trouble getting my objects to print the way I want them to using __str__. I want each Task object to be printed with the word "DONE!" if the task has been completed (i.e. the index 2 for the task object is equal to 1), but each time I call viewCompleted() the program returns each object as a tuple.

The if statement in the main module that calls viewCompleted():

```
import Task_List_Database as tld

if user_command.lower() == "history":
            tld.viewCompleted()
```

Object Constructor and __str__

```
class Task:
    def __init__(self, taskID, description, completed):
        self.taskID = taskID
        self.description = description
        self.completed = completed

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description + " DONE!"
```

```
import sqlite3
import Task_List_Objects as tlo

conn = sqlite3.connect("task_list_db.sqlite")
c = conn.cursor()

def readDatabase():
    query = '''SELECT * FROM Task'''
    c.execute(query)
    tasks = c.fetchall()

    for task in tasks:
        tlo.Task(task[0], task[1], task[2])

    return tasks

def viewCompleted():
    tasks = readDatabase()

    task_count = 1
    for task in tasks:
        if task[2] == 1:
            print(task)
        task_count += 1
    print()
```

Output where __str__ problem occurs:

```
Command: history
(1, 'Get bike fixed', 1)
(2, 'Call your mom', 1)
(3, 'Buy toothbrush', 1)
(4, 'Do homework', 1)
```

Any help explaining why __str__ isn't working the way I intend would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `tasks` is just the output from `c.fetchall`, not `Task` instances.

Comment: You are returning `tasks` in `readDatabase()`, aka tuples. I believe you want to be returning a list of `Task` instances.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the `.fetchall()` not the new class instance, so you can hack it to print it:

```
class Task:
    def __init__(self, taskID, description, completed):
        self.taskID = taskID
        self.description = description
        self.completed = completed

    def __str__(self):
        print(self.description + " DONE!")
```

And make the other class like

```
def readDatabase():
    query = '''SELECT * FROM Task'''
    c.execute(query)
    tasks = c.fetchall()

    for task in tasks:
        tlo.Task(task[0], task[1], task[2])
```

And call like

```
readDatabase()
```